# Parametric Plot 3D, Helix and Astroidal Sphere

Tags: graphics, 3d

Can somebody help me with creating two plots -- a Helix and an Astroidal Sphere -- in LaTeX? The attached pictures are screenshots from Mathematica and show the desired results.

[image: Helix]

[image: Astroidal Sphere]

Comment: Hi Reina [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you want to do in LaTeX. Do yo need to insert those two pictures inside a document, or are you trying to generate them inside LaTeX instead of Mathematica?

Comment: I have so many packages in my document, so it's not a problem. I want to draw a picture in Latex, and all I have is this parametric equations:  x(u,v)=[ 1.2+0.5*Cos(v)]*Cos(u) ,  y(u,v)=[1.2+0.5*Cos(v)]Sin(u) ,   z(u,v)=0.5*Sin(v)+ u/pi   where is:  0<u<4pi  and  0<v<2pi

Comment: If you speak Spanish and feel more comfortable asking in Spanish, you can subscribe in the [mail list of the CervanTeX]() and ask there also. There is not much activity as here, but it can help yourself for future reference.

Regarding your question, I don't know how convenient is redo your figures into `LaTeX`, but if you want to try, `Tikz` is the package you should use. One of its many libraries is suitable to draw figures like these.

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95247/how-to-draw-a-mexican-hat-potential-using-3dplot/95252#95252) related with yours, I hope you find it useful.

Since I am still a newbie in `Tikz` I can't help you so much.

Comment: I'm from Bosnia, I don't speak Spanish..I don't need all, just how to write this equations in Latex.. But nevermind thanks for try to help me ;)

Comment: Sorry, I made a bad inference from your nickname. And my notions of Bosnian (aka Serbo-Croatian) are worse than my English, so there will not help.

Answer (score 5):

Run with `xelatex` (takes some time) or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.75}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-4)(3,6)
\psset{viewpoint=20 70 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=20,lightsrc=viewpoint}
% Parametric Surfaces
\defFunction[algebraic]{helix}(u,v)
 {(1.2+0.5*cos(v))*cos(u)}
 {(1.2+0.5*cos(v))*sin(u)}
 {0.5*sin(v)+u/Pi}
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
 base=-7 6.5 0 TwoPi,hue=0 1,function=helix,ngrid=30 0.4]%
\gridIIID[Zmin=-3,Zmax=3](-2,2)(-2,2)
\end{pspicture}

\psset{unit=3cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\psset{viewpoint=20 70 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=20,lightsrc=viewpoint}
% Parametric Surfaces
\defFunction[algebraic]{helix}(u,v)
 {(cos(v)*cos(u))^3}
 {(cos(v)*sin(u))^3}
 {sin(v)^3}
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
 base=0 Pi 0 TwoPi,fillcolor=red,function=helix,ngrid=20 40]%
\gridIIID[Zmin=-1,Zmax=1,showAxes=false](-1,1)(-1,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: OMG :D thank you, thank you, thank you soooo much Herbert  :D

Comment: The labels are in text mode, e.g., the minus sign `-` are hyphens. Is this a bug?

Comment: seems so. I'll upload a new version to CTAN

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2, xscale=1]
  \begin{axis}[axis line style={draw=none}, 
      view={170}{-20},
      grid=major,
      xmin=0,xmax=2,
      ymin=0,ymax=2,
      zmin=0,zmax=4,
      enlargelimits=upper,
      xtick=\empty,
      ytick=\empty,
      ztick=\empty,
      %colormap/bone,
      trig format plots=rad,
      clip=false
    ]
    \addplot3 [ surf, domain=0:12.566, domain y=0:6.28,
      samples=70, samples y=70,
      variable=\u, variable y=\v,
    point meta=u*v, opacity=0.4 ]
     ({(1.2+0.5*cos(v))*cos(u)},
     {(1.2+0.5*cos(v))*sin(u)},
     {0.5*sin(v)+u/(3.0)});


  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here the picture
[image: helicoida]