# How to draw a real corkscrew

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, decorations

I would like to draw a real screw like in image below. Any codes in tikz, asymptote or pstricks are welcomed!

[image: screw1]
In order do not confuse with my linked question about laser who as well
is based on helix I would like to add a note:
I do need Corkscrew in order to predict the direction of the magnetic field lines around a straight conductor through which a steady electric current is flowing.

[image][image]

and my attempts do not correspond to reality
[image: screw2]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, line join=round]
\draw [line width=0.2mm,double=gray!70,decorate, decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.1cm,post
length=0.1cm,segment length=6},line join=round](0,-.75)  -> (1,-.75);
\draw [line width=0.1mm,double=gray!70,decorate, decoration={coil,pre length=0.1cm,post
length=0.1cm,segment length=2,amplitude=1mm},line join=round](0,-1.25)  ->   (1,-1.25); 
\draw [thick,double=gray!70,decorate, decoration={snake,pre length=0.1cm,post
length=0.1cm,segment length=6},line join=round](0,-1.75)  -> (1,-1.75);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or maybe [Reproducing image of a spiral using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217508/reproducing-image-of-a-spiral-using-tikz)

[image: screw3]
please any ideas?

Comment: This could help [parametric plot 3D, helix and astroidal sphere](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199562)  though I'm not sure TikZ is the right tool for this.

Comment: Yes, something similar, but I prefer in tikz

Comment: Your linked question should be the way to go, since all the answers there define a helix.

Comment: I'm so disappointed by your edit: I thought you planned to build a laser enhanced corkscrew that would blast the cork with a red lightsaber

Comment: I'm glad that now you got it!

Answer (score 11):

With the help of [the stl file reader in asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282390/8425) and [an stl file rendering a corkscrew](http://www.thingiverse.com/download:85049), you can get this:

[image]

```
settings.outformat = "png";
settings.render = 8;
import three;
size(20cm);

struct stringpointer { string s; }

surface readstlfile(string filename, stringpointer returnsurfacename=null, bool ascii=true) {
  assert(ascii, "Reading binary stl files not implemented.");
  file stlfile = input(filename).word();  // Set up a file to read whitespace-delimited items.
  string nextword;
  real x, y, z;

  nextword = stlfile;  // Reading from a file is done by assignment in Asymptote.
  assert(nextword == "solid", filename + " is not a well-formed stl file.");

  string name = stlfile;
  if (returnsurfacename != null) returnsurfacename.s = name;

  surface toreturn;

  while (!eof(stlfile)) {
    nextword = stlfile;
    if (nextword == "endsolid") break;
    else if (nextword == "facet") {

      nextword = stlfile;
      assert(nextword == "normal");

      x = stlfile; y = stlfile; z = stlfile;
      triple normal = (x, y, z);

      nextword = stlfile; assert(nextword == "outer");
      nextword = stlfile; assert(nextword == "loop");
      triple[] vertices = new triple[3];
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    nextword = stlfile; assert(nextword == "vertex");
    x = stlfile; y = stlfile; z = stlfile;
    vertices[i] = (x,y,z);
      }
      nextword = stlfile; assert(nextword == "endloop");
      nextword = stlfile; assert(nextword == "endfacet");

      patch triangle = patch(vertices[0] -- vertices[1] -- vertices[2] -- cycle);
      triangle.normals = array(4, value=normal);
      toreturn.s.push(triangle);

    } else assert(false, filename + " is not a well-formed stl file.");
  }
  assert(nextword == "endsolid", filename + " does not end correctly.");
  nextword = stlfile;
  assert(nextword == name, filename + " does not end with the solid's correct name " + name);
  return toreturn;
}

currentprojection = perspective(-30, 10, 60);
surface corkscrew = readstlfile("Corkscrew1.stl");
draw(corkscrew, blue);
```