# Illustrating Stokes theorem with asymptote

Tags: 3d, asymptote

I want to use `asymptote` to illustrate Stokes theorem as in the following figure.

[image: Cronholm144 (Own work) [GFDL (http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html), CC-BY-SA-3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) or CC BY-SA 2.5-2.0-1.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5-2.0-1.0)], via Wikimedia Commons]

Here is what I've done so far.

```
import three;
size(6cm,0);

path path2D = (1, 0) .. (2, 1) .. (0, 2) .. (-2.25, 1) .. (-1.5, 0) .. (-1, -1) .. (0, -1.75) .. (1, -2) .. cycle;

path3 path3D = path3(path2D, XYplane);

draw(path3D, red, arrow = Arrow3(emissive(black), position = Relative(.9)), L = Label("$\mathcal{C}$", align = S, position = Relative(.9)));

int imax = 10;

for(int i = 1; i < imax; ++i) {
  draw(shift((0, 0, i / (imax / 2))) * scale3(sqrt((imax - i - .9)/imax)) * path3D);
}
```

[image]

1. How can I draw a surface "guided" by black paths and "lying" on the red path?
2. How can I "randomize" a bit more the black guides and, consequently, the surface (the Stokes theorem states that one can choose any surface lying on the path)?
3. Once the surface is defined, given a point M belonging to it, is it possible to get the normal vector in M (and then reuse the c[orkscrew question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285576/8425) `:)`)?

Comment: Suggestion: Use the `smoothSurface(triple[][])` function from [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226235/484) to construct a surface from a matrix of `triple`s.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Ok. But how do I get the matrix of `triple`s? Is there a `path` to `array` predefined?

Comment: Not so far as I know, but `point(path p, int i)` will give you the `i`th point on the path `p`. Using a `for` loop will allow you to extract all the points from the path. (For your purposes, each path has points numbered 0,1,...,8.)

Comment: @CharlesStaats Good point. But my path is build with the operator `..`, so asymptote adds some control points, so if I extract points with `point`, I won't get the smooth path and consequently the surface won't be smooth, will it?

Comment: The `smoothSurface` function described referenced above will end up recreating your smooth paths in the process of building a smooth surface. (Or you could just use the `point` function to parametrize your surface and plot it that way.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image]

In this solution the surface is defined by function

```
triple f(pair z){
  path3 p;
  p=shift((0, 0, log(1+z.y / (imax / 2)))) * scale3(sqrt(1-(z.y^2)/imax^2)) * path3D;  
  return relpoint(p,z.x);
}
```

It takes two arguments: `z.x` defines a fraction of arclength of the horizontal path,
and `z.y` defines vertical shift.

Given a point `M` on the surface as

```
triple M=f((Mxy,Mz));
```

the normal vector is constructed as a cross product 
of direction vectors 
of two paths on the surface (`u-path` and `v-path`).
at the point `M`.

Complete code:

```
import graph3;
size(6cm,0);

currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(4.3,2,4.5),
up=Z,target=(-0.1,0.1,0.06),zoom=0.9);

path path2D = (1, 0) .. (2, 1) .. (0, 2) .. (-2.25, 1) .. (-1.5, 0) .. (-1, -1) .. (0, -1.75) .. (1, -2) .. cycle;

path3 path3D = path3(path2D, XYplane);

int imax = 8;

    triple f(pair z){
      path3 p;
      p=shift((0, 0, log(1+z.y / (imax / 2)))) * scale3(sqrt(1-(z.y^2)/imax^2)) * path3D;  
      return relpoint(p,z.x);
    }

real Mxy=0.31;
real Mz=2;

triple M=f((Mxy,Mz));

real ux(real t) {return f((t,Mz)).x;}
real uy(real t) {return f((t,Mz)).y;}
real uz(real t) {return f((t,Mz)).z;}

real vx(real t) {return f((Mxy,t)).x;}
real vy(real t) {return f((Mxy,t)).y;}
real vz(real t) {return f((Mxy,t)).z;}

guide3 gu=graph(ux,uy,uz,0,1,operator..);
guide3 gv=graph(vx,vy,vz,0,imax,operator..);


real t=intersect(gu,gv)[1];

triple du=dir(gu,reltime(gu,Mxy));
triple dv=dir(gv,t);

triple normal=unit(cross(du,dv));

arrowbar3 ar=Arrow3(emissive(black), position = Relative(.9));
arrowbar3 arn=Arrow3(emissive(black));

draw(path3D, red, arrow = ar, L = Label("$\mathcal{C}$", align = S, position = Relative(.9)));
draw(surface(f,(0,0),(1,imax)
  ,nu=30
  ,Spline,Spline),orange+opacity(0.5)
);

draw(gu, deepblue);
draw(gv, brown);

dot(M);
draw(M--(M+normal),arn);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time (+1): great job! I need to study a bit what you've done but it sounds promising!

Comment: How did you choose `shift((0, 0, log(1+z.y / (imax / 2))))`. What other options do we have here?

Comment: @cjorssen: You can try for example, 
`shift((0, 0, (1-exp(-z.y / (imax / 2))) ))`
or something similar with `sqrt` or any other function 
that provides more-or-less  smooth shape.

Answer (score 14):

[image: wibbly wobbly]

I wouldn't recommend your approach.

> 1. How can I draw a surface "guided" by black paths and "lying" on the
>      red path?
> 2. How can I "randomize" a bit more the black guides and, consequently,
>      the surface (the Stokes theorem states that one can choose any
>      surface lying on the path)?
> 3. Once the surface is defined, given a point M belonging to it, is it
>      possible to get the normal vector in M (and then reuse the corkscrew
>      question :))?

While "lying" has a clear univoque meaning (i.e. the path is the boundary of the surface) there is an infinity of possibilities for "guided" and "randomized". Furthermore, the ease of computing the normal vector depends very much on that choice.

Maybe I'm missing something, but if you just care about illustrating Stokes' Theorem I see no reason to build some surface from a family of sections.

I'd say that you just want the surface to look like *wibbly wobbly stuff*. I suggest a parametrized surface (and some good lighting): this way you immediately have a precise parametric normal vector on an easily chosen point.

```
import graph3;
size(6cm,0);
settings.render = 4;
currentprojection=orthographic(4, 1, 1);

// COORDINATE SYSTEM
label("$O$", (0, 0, 0), NW);
Label Lx = Label("$x$", EndPoint, W);
Label Ly = Label("$y$", EndPoint, S);
Label Lz = Label("$z$", EndPoint, W);
draw(Lx, O--2X, Arrow3(emissive(black)));
draw(Ly, O--2Y, Arrow3(emissive(black)));
draw(Lz, O--2Z, Arrow3(emissive(black)));

// SURFACE
triple S(pair uv) {
  real x = cos(uv.x)*sin(uv.y);
  real y = sin(uv.x)*sin(uv.y);
  real z =           cos(uv.y);
  return (x-(1-z**2-y**2), y-0.3*sin(z*pi), z);
}

// BOUNDARY
triple dS(real u) {
  return S((u, pi/2));
}

// TANGENT VECTORS
real e = 0.001; // *this... is... infinitesimal!*
triple U(pair t) { return (S((e,0)+t)-S(t))/e; }
triple V(pair t) { return (S((0,e)+t)-S(t))/e; }

// NORMAL VECTOR
triple N(pair uv) {
  return cross(U(uv),V(uv))/length(cross(U(uv),V(uv)));
}

// GRAPHICAL ELEMENTS

surface s = surface(S, (0, 0), (2pi, pi/2), 64, 64, Spline);
path3 ds = graph(dS, 0, 2pi);

pair t = (-pi/8, pi/8);
path3 n = S(t) -- shift(-N(t))*S(t);

triple adj = (0,1.4,0.7);
s = shift(adj)*s;
ds = shift(adj)*ds;
n = shift(adj)*n;

label("$\Sigma$", shift(0,0,0.1)*shift(adj)*S((pi/2,pi/5)), NE);
Label LdS = Label("$\partial\Sigma$", Relative(0.95), S);
Label Ln = Label("$\mathbf n$", EndPoint, NW);

draw(s, surfacepen=material(diffusepen=gray(0.6),emissivepen=gray(0.3),specularpen=gray(0.1)));
draw(LdS, ds, Arrow3(emissive(black)));
draw(shift(4*unit(currentprojection.camera))*ds, dashed);
draw(Ln, n, Arrow3(emissive(black)));
```

---

**REQUESTED APPENDIX: on dashed lines**

*(adapted from comments)*

I wanted to draw the dashed border over the surface. Since this is an orthographic projection, the easiest way is translating the object along the camera axis towards it (instead of checking what segments are visible, possibly complicated):

```
draw(shift(4*unit(currentprojection.camera))*ds, dashed);
```

`unit(currentprojection.camera)` is a versor parallel to the camera axis and pointing towards it, so it comes in handy for a shift. `4` isn't random. Note that a bounding volume for the surface also (obviously) bounds the border. If the surface was a unitary sphere a good bound would be the sphere itself, so a displacement of `2` (twice the radius) would guarantee tangency for the bounding spheres of surface and path, hence their non-intersection. Unfortunately our surface is a deformed sphere:

```
triple S(pair uv) {
  real x = cos(uv.x)*sin(uv.y);
  real y = sin(uv.x)*sin(uv.y);
  real z =           cos(uv.y);
  return (x-(1-z**2-y**2), y-0.3*sin(z*pi), z);
}
```

However the deformation seems to never exceed `1` in any direction on every point:

```
(-(1-z**2-y**2), -0.3*sin(z*pi), 0)
```

Is it possible that the deformation itself is locally bound by a unitary sphere? Let's find out: if I choke Mathematica with `RegionPlot[{Norm[{-(1-z^2-y^2),-0.3*Sin[z*Pi],0}]<1,Norm[{0,y,z}]<1},{z,-2,2},{y,-2,2},PlotLegends->"Expressions"]` it outputs

[image: blerp]

This means that the volume (a cylinder whose sections are blue) in which the postulated defomation bound is safe to use extends well beyond where we need it (the surface of a sphere whose projection is orange). Victory!

What is the bounding volume of the deformed surface? Take the initial bound, the sphere itself, and attach to every point the deformation bound, i.e. an unitary sphere. What do we get? A bounding sphere of radius `2`. So by our old agument a displacement of `4` (twice the augmented bounding sphere radius) is safe.

The displacing trick itself would work with any projection in which the light rays are parallel (camera at infinity). This means that it fails only with perspective cameras.

Comment: Suggestion to further improve this beautiful picture: Make the surface opaque, but shift it away from the camera so that the boundary path is still visible.

Comment: Thanks for your time (+1): you did a great job too. This is indeed another interesting approach.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Good idea; answer updated.

Comment: @cjorssen Thanks. This is my very first picture with asymptote. After g.kov posted his solution too I learnt a couple of new tricks so I updated my answer, incorporating Charles suggestion.

Comment: Great. But I'm afraid I don't understand the magic behind `4*unit(currentprojection.camera)`. Did you get `4` by trial and error?  Does it work for other projection types?

Comment: Very nice. Nothing could improve upon it much, I think. The dashed line looks like the one in the OP´s example illustration, but it is not as naturalistic as a solid line, maybe just a little darker than the material colour. I am not fond of asymptote´s 3d arrows, but we don´t have much choice there.

Comment: @cjorssen I wanted to draw the dashed border over the surface. Since this is an orthographic projection, the easiest way is translating the object along the camera axis towards it (instead of checking what segments are visible, possibly complicated). `unit(currentprojection.camera)` is a versor pointing from the origin to the camera position, so it comes in handy. `4` isn't random. If the surface was a sphere a good bounding shape would be the sphere itself, so a displacement of `2` (double of the radius) would guarantee tangency of the bounding spheres of surface and path [continues...]

Comment: @cjorssen [...continued] hence their non-intersection. Our surface is a deformed sphere, but the deformation does not exceed `1` in any direction on every point. This means that a sphere of radius `2` is bounding and by the same argument as before a displacement of `4` (double of the bounding spheres radius) is safe. The displacing trick itself would work with any projection in which the light rays are parallel (camera at infinity). So it fails only with perspective.

Comment: Thanks. If you have time, may I ask you to complete your answer with your comments (possibly with images as illustrations).

Comment: @cjorssen Done.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay: There is a fair amount you can do with 3d arrows in Asymptote (e.g., make them look 2d and--optionally--embed them in a plane of your choice); see section 3.13 of [my tutorial](http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf).