# Making the determination of extrema more elegant in TikZ (not pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf

It is rather straightforward to come up with a rusty code that determines the extremal points of an arbitrary path in Ti*k*Z. I am aware that [pgfplots has this functionality](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55352/121799), but I really want to have this functionality for all paths and have applications in mind that are sort of orthogonal to pgfplots. Here is my rusty code.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatletter
\def\GetPathBB{
  \typeout{path:(\the\pgf@pathminx,\the\pgf@pathminy),(\the\pgf@pathmaxx,\the\pgf@pathmaxy)}
  \xdef\BBmin{\the\pgf@pathminx,\the\pgf@pathminy}
  \xdef\BBmax{\the\pgf@pathmaxx,\the\pgf@pathmaxy}
}
\makeatother  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (5.5,0) node[above] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-3) -- (0,4) node[left] {$y$};
\draw[blue,thick,name path=myplot] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:5] ({\x},{cos(-20+50*\x)})
\pgfextra{\GetPathBB}; %<- instead of inserting this "by hand" I'd like to 
% put this into an option of the path command, but all my attempts
% with "append after command" or "postaction" failed
\path[name path global=minline] (\BBmin)  to[bend left=0] (\BBmin-|\BBmax);
\path [name intersections={of=minline and myplot, name=min}];
\draw[fill=red] (min-1) circle (2pt) node[below] {min};
\path[name path global=maxline] (\BBmin|-\BBmax)  to[bend left=0] (\BBmax);
\path [name intersections={of=maxline and myplot, name=max}];
\draw[fill=red] (max-1) circle (2pt) node[above] {max};
% the extrema should also be computed automatically, ideally also the leftmost
% and rightmost points 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It works:

[image]

and you can also find some extremal points of other paths:

[image]

It is also obvious how to find the left- and rightmost points of the path. However, the code is not too elegant. It would be much nicer if one could just pass an option `find extrema` to the plot and not have the above mess. Specifically, I'd like to absorb the `\pgfextra{...}` before the semicolon and the codes for `maxline` and `minline` in this option. I played a bit with `append after command`, `postaction` and the like, but I failed.

Comment: For that TikZ has `current path bounding box` node that does these computations.But if you use control points, this approach will fail.

Comment: @percusse Yes, that's already a great help, now I can simply write `\draw[blue,thick,name path=myplot] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:5] ({\x},{cos(-20+50*\x)})
coordinate (BBmax) at (current path bounding box.north east) 
coordinate (BBmin) at (current path bounding box.south west);` but I still fail to convert this to a style.

Comment: For that you need a plot handler. There are some ideas here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249860/compute-and-draw-a-convex-hull/

Comment: @percusse Your suggestion works really great, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423688/121799). Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `path picture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\tikzset{name path min max/.style = {
    name path global=#1,
    path picture={
      \coordinate (ll) at (path picture bounding box.south west);
      \coordinate (ur) at (path picture bounding box.north east);
      \path[name path=minline] (ll) to[bend left=0] (ll-|ur);
      \path[name intersections={of=minline and #1, name=#1-min}];
      \path[name path=maxline] (ll|-ur) to[bend left=0] (ur);
      \path[name intersections={of=maxline and #1, name=#1-max}];
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (5.5,0) node[above] {$x$};
  \draw[-latex] (0,-1.5) -- (0,2) node[left] {$y$};

  \draw[blue,thick,name path min max=myplot] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:5] ({\x},{cos(-20+50*\x)});

  % Use min and max
  \draw[fill=red] (myplot-min-1) circle (2pt) node[below] {min};
  \draw[fill=red] (myplot-max-1) circle (2pt) node[above] {max};

  % Reuse path in other intersections
  \path[name path=diag] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \path[name intersections={of=diag and myplot, name=inter}];
  \node[draw,fill=green,circle,inner sep=2pt] at (inter-1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot More bells and whistles...

Comment: Very, very clever ! And very nice code.

Comment: @marmot I hope this is more like your taste ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WINQ.png)).  Thanks for the suggestions, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Those who may want to use this for smooth curves may be interested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501154/121799) which determines the true bounding box. Otherwise Ti*k*Z may not find an intersection.