# Label alignment to curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I would like to align the label "Wave 1" to the center of the red curve in the  vertical direction. I still want it to be placed the same way in the horizontal direction. See the picture.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\scale{0.3}

\path[use as bounding box] (0,8) rectangle (7,10);

\draw[scale=0.5,domain=3:8,smooth,variable=\x,red] plot ({\x+1}, 
{\scale*sin(deg(\x+4))+17}) node[anchor=east,xshift = -2.5cm ] {Wave 1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try going theother way `\draw[red] node[inner sep=0] (w1) {Wave 1} {[shift={(w1.east)}] plot[domain=0:0.97*pi] (\x, {0.2*sin(1.5*(0.15*pi+\x) r)}) };`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways. For example, the following stores the current position after the plot in the node `tmp` for the horizontal component. Then it is combined with the middle vertical position (`\yoffset`) of the curve by using perpendicular coordinates.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\scale{0.3}
  \newcommand\yoffset{17}

  \draw[scale=0.5, domain=3:8, smooth, variable=\x, red]
    plot ({\x+1}, {\scale*sin(deg(\x+4)) + \yoffset})
    coordinate (tmp) (tmp |- 0, \yoffset)
    node[anchor=east,xshift = -2.5cm] {Wave 1}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If the curve is the *first* element in the picture, then the current bounding box can be used to find the left middle point of the curve. This gets rid of `xshift` and the magic dimension `-2.5cm`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\scale{0.3}
  \newcommand\yoffset{17}

  \draw[scale=0.5, domain=3:8, smooth, variable=\x, red]
    plot ({\x+1}, {\scale*sin(deg(\x+4)) + \yoffset})
    (current bounding box.west)
    node[anchor=east] {Wave 1}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If the curve is not the first element, then the current bounding box can be saved, and restored afterwards:

```
\draw[scale=\plotScale, domain=3:8, smooth, variable=\x, red]
  % Save current bounding box and clear the box
  (current bounding box.south west) coordinate (bbll)
  (current bounding box.north east) coordinate (bbur)
  \pgfextra{\pgfresetboundingbox}
  %
  plot ({\x+1}, {\scale*sin(deg(\x+4)) + \yoffset})
  (current bounding box.west)
  node[anchor=east] {Wave 1}
  %
  % Add old bounding box to current bounding box.
  (bbll) (bbur)
;
```

In this case, with one path, the example can be simplified by using `current path bounding box.west`, see the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424293/label-alignment-to-curve/424308?noredirect=1#comment1061541_424308) of Kpym.

Another variation. The left point of the wave can be easily calculated:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\scale{0.3}
  \newcommand\yoffset{17}
  \newcommand\plotScale{.5}
  \newcommand\domainMin{3}
  \newcommand\domainMax{8}

  \draw[
    scale=\plotScale,
    domain=\domainMin:\domainMax,
    smooth,
    variable=\x,
    red,
  ]
    plot ({\x+1}, {\scale*sin(deg(\x+4)) + \yoffset})
    (\domainMin + 1, \yoffset)
    node[anchor=east] {Wave 1}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The `(current bounding box)` will not work if there is another path before this one in the picture, I think.

Comment: @Kpym Therefore  I have written "If the curve is the *first* element in the picture".

Comment: You can replace `(current bounding box.west)` with `(current path bounding box.west)`, I think, and in this case it will work even if it is not the first element.

Comment: @Kpym Thanks, `current path bounding box.west` works.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method that uses the bounding box of the path (inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423952/9335) and section 15.6 of the pgfmanual).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\tikzset{mark path extrema/.style = {
    path picture={
      \coordinate (#1-bl) at (path picture bounding box.south west);
      \coordinate (#1-tr) at (path picture bounding box.north east);
      \coordinate (#1-br) at (path picture bounding box.south east);
      \coordinate (#1-tl) at (path picture bounding box.north west);
    }
  }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\scale{0.3}

\path[use as bounding box] (0,8) rectangle (7,10);

\draw[scale=0.5,domain=3:8,smooth,variable=\x,red,mark path extrema=wave] plot ({\x+1}, 
{\scale*sin(deg(\x+4))+17}); 
\node[anchor=east] at ($(wave-tl)!0.5!(wave-bl)$){Wave 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this is to save the bounding box of your curve with `local bounding box` and then use this node to position your text wherever you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\newcommand\scale{0.3}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[scale=0.5, domain=3:8, smooth,variable=\x, red, local bounding box = wave]
      plot ({\x+1},{\scale*sin(deg(\x+4))+17});
    \node[right] at (wave.east) {Wave on East};
    \node[left] at (wave.west) {Wave on West};
    \draw[opacity=.1,step = 2pt] (wave.south east) grid (wave.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]