# How to plot two surfaces and the intersection curve?

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d, pst-3dplot

I want to draw the intersection line (curve line) of two functions `x^2+y^2+z^2=4` (`Zmin= 0`) and `x^2+y^2=2y` in the same coordinate system as follows.

[image]

I have read `pst-3dplot` and `pst-solides3d` but I can only draw the following.

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-3dplot,pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\pstThreeDCoor

\psImplicitSurface[XMinMax=-2.0 2.0 0.15,YMinMax=-2.0 2.0 0.15,ZMinMax= 0 2.25 0.15,algebraic,ImplFunction=x^2+y^2+z^2-4]%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

## Question

How to plot two surfaces and the intersection curve?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-2)(6,6)
\psset{viewpoint=30 40 40 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\psset{solidmemory,opacity=0.75}
\axesIIID(0,0,0)(3,3,3)
\psSolid[%
object=cylindrecreux,
r=1,
h=2,
ngrid=36 36,
fillcolor=red,
incolor=orange,
action=none,
name=A1](0,1,0)%
\psSolid[%
object=calottesphere,
r=2,
ngrid=36 36,
action=none,
name=B1]
\psSolid[object=fusion,
base=A1 B1,
action=draw**]
\composeSolid
% Equation of "Window of Viviani"
\defFunction[algebraic]{g}(t)%
{sin(t)}%
{cos(t)+1}%
{2*sin(1/2*t)}
\psSolid[%
object=courbe,
range=0 6.28,
fillcolor=yellow,
linewidth=0,
function=g,
name=C1,
opacity=0.9,
r=0.0125]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 23):

A quick Ti*k*Z version for comparison.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3,declare function={
myz(\x)=sqrt((1-sin(\x))/2);}]
\draw[-latex] (-2,0,0)  -- (2,0,0) node[pos=1.05]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) coordinate(O)  -- (0,2,0) node[pos=1.1]{$y$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0)  -- (0,0,2) node[pos=1.1]{$z$};
\begin{scope}
 \clip plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi-180:90,smooth] 
 ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},0)--
  plot[variable=\x,domain=90:450,smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},{myz(\x)})--
 plot[variable=\x,domain=90:\tdplotmainphi,smooth] ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},0) -- ++ (0,0,2) --
 ({cos(\tdplotmainphi-180)},{sin(\tdplotmainphi-180)},2) -- cycle; 
 \draw[ball color=gray,opacity=0.3,tdplot_screen_coords] (O) circle (1);
\end{scope}
\draw[top color=gray,bottom color=gray!30,middle color=gray!20,shading angle=90,
fill opacity=0.3]  plot[variable=\x,domain=90:450,smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},{myz(\x)});
\shade[top color=gray!50,bottom color=gray!50!black,middle color=gray,shading angle=90,
fill opacity=0.3]  plot[variable=\x,domain=90:-64,smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},{myz(\x)})
--plot[variable=\x,domain=-64:90,smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},0);
\draw[dashed] plot[variable=\x,domain=90:-64,smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},0) --
({0.5*cos(-64)},{0.5+0.5*sin(-64)},{myz(-64)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADENDUM**: Very often when doing such 3d plots one encounters the challenge to find the coordinates on a path that correspond to the, say, leftmost point. In addition, one would sometimes like to have the 3d coordinates. The cleanest way is to derive these analytically as a function of the view angle. For instance, one may want to know the find the angle of the leftmost point of the upper boundary of the cylinder, i.e. the intersection curve sphere and cylinder. However, in this example this task is already rather hard. That's why the above code has a hard-coded value 64 which was found by trial and error. This value is a reasonable guess for the view angles chosen. But what if one wants to change the view?

This addendum addresses this with a style `mark path extrema`, which is similar in spirit to [Henri Menke's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423952/121799) but different in two ways:

- Henri's solution works fine in many cases but it does happen occasionally that the intersections cannot be found. The following proposal will always find a point. Of course the precision is not infinite.
- Even if one has the point in form of a symbolic coordinate, one does not have the 3d coordinate. The following solution allows one to infer the point at least for plots with reasonable accuracy. (Note that it is possible to achieve the same effects with the pgfplots (!) library `fillbetween` but the compilation takes even longer with this option, and the naming of the intersection segments depends in general on the view angles, which complicates things such that it is hard to produce animations.)

Of course, I am doing this only to produce an animation. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcounter{emark}
\newcounter{emarkN}
\newcounter{emarkS}
\newcounter{emarkW}
\newcounter{emarkE}
\newcommand\ReadjustExtrema{% \pgfextra{\typeout{\y1,\y2,\x3,\x4}}
\ifnum\theemark=0
\path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (eauxN)
coordinate (eauxS) coordinate (eauxW) coordinate (eauxE);
\path let \p1=($(eauxN)-(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$),
\p2=($(eauxS)-(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$),
\p3=($(eauxW)-(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$),
\p4=($(eauxE)-(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)
in 
\ifdim\y1<0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (eauxN) [set emark=N]
\fi
\ifdim\y2>0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (eauxS) [set emark=S]
\fi
\ifdim\x3>0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (eauxW) [set emark=W]
\fi
\ifdim\x4<0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (eauxE) [set emark=E]
\fi
;
\else
\path let \p1=($(eauxN)-(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$),
\p2=($(eauxS)-(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$),
\p3=($(eauxW)-(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$),
\p4=($(eauxE)-(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)$)
in 
\ifdim\y1<0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (eauxN) [set emark=N]
\fi
\ifdim\y2>0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (eauxS) [set emark=S]
\fi
\ifdim\x3>0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (eauxW) [set emark=W]
\fi
\ifdim\x4<0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (eauxE) [set emark=E]
\fi
;
\path let \p1=($(eauxN)-(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$),
\p2=($(eauxS)-(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$),
\p3=($(eauxW)-(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$),
\p4=($(eauxE)-(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)
in 
\ifdim\y1<0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (eauxN) [set emark=N]
\fi
\ifdim\y2>0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (eauxS) [set emark=S]
\fi
\ifdim\x3>0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (eauxW) [set emark=W]
\fi
\ifdim\x4<0pt
(\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (eauxE) [set emark=E]
\fi
;
\fi
\stepcounter{emark}}
\tikzset{mark path extrema/.style={reset emark,
postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
          show path construction,
          moveto code={\ReadjustExtrema},
          lineto code={\ReadjustExtrema},
          curveto code={\ReadjustExtrema}}}
          },reset emark/.code={\setcounter{emark}{0}
          \setcounter{emarkN}{0}\setcounter{emarkS}{0}
          \setcounter{emarkW}{0}\setcounter{emarkE}{0}},
          set emark/.code={\setcounter{emark#1}{\theemark}}
          }
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {5,15,...,355}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{70+10*cos(\X)}{140+20*sin(\X)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3,declare function={
myz(\x)=sqrt((1-sin(\x))/2);}]
\path [tdplot_screen_coords,use as bounding box] (-2.5,-1) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
\draw[-latex] (-2,0,0)  -- (2,0,0) node[pos=1.05]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) coordinate(O)  -- (0,2,0) node[pos=1.1]{$y$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0)  -- (0,0,2) node[pos=1.1]{$z$};
\begin{scope}
 \clip plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi-180:90,smooth] 
 ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},0)--
  plot[variable=\x,domain=90:450,smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},{myz(\x)})--
 plot[variable=\x,domain=90:\tdplotmainphi,smooth] ({cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},0) -- ++ (0,0,2) --
 ({cos(\tdplotmainphi-180)},{sin(\tdplotmainphi-180)},2) -- cycle; 
 \draw[ball color=gray,opacity=0.3,tdplot_screen_coords] (O) circle (1);
\end{scope}
\draw[top color=gray,bottom color=gray!30,middle color=gray!20,shading angle=90,
fill opacity=0.3,mark path extrema]  plot[variable=\x,domain=90:450,smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},{myz(\x)});
\coordinate (pW) at (eauxW);
\coordinate (pE) at (eauxE);
\def\stepW{\theemarkW}
\def\stepE{\theemarkE}
\draw[dashed,mark path extrema] plot[variable=\x,domain=90:450,smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},0); 
\shade[top color=gray!50,bottom color=gray!50!black,middle color=gray,shading angle=90,
fill opacity=0.3] plot[variable=\x,domain=450:{90+3.6*\theemarkW},smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},{0})
-- plot[variable=\x,domain={90+3.6*\stepW}:450,smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},{myz(\x)});
\shade[top color=gray!50,bottom color=gray!50!black,middle color=gray,shading
angle=-90,fill opacity=0.3] 
plot[variable=\x,domain=90:{90+3.6*\theemarkE},smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},{0})
-- plot[variable=\x,domain={90+3.6*\stepE}:90,smooth,samples=101] 
({0.5*cos(\x)},{0.5+0.5*sin(\x)},{myz(\x)});
\draw[dashed] (pW) -- (eauxW) (pE) -- (eauxE);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Beautiful picture!

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy I imagined it was just a matter of time :-). We still need the dotted part. However spectacular everything.

Comment: +1 for spending your space, time, energy for drawing this that has become  realistic.

Comment: This is amazing and all, but this seems like something that should be done in matplotlib and exported to pdf?

Comment: @NeilG Sure, you can do that with Mathematica, asymptote, matplotlib and many other tools with much less effort, and you will get a realistic lighting and so on. With asymptote you'd also have the possibility to use LaTeX to do the annotations. A very related discussion can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459883/121799). I guess doing these things this way can make sense for those who want to produce some lecture notes and want to have all arrows and texts have the same style.

Answer (score 12):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4,-2)(6,6)
\psset{viewpoint=30 10 20 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\psSolid[object=plan,
  definition=normalpoint,args={0 0 0 [0 0 1]},
  base=-2.5 2.5 -2.5 2.5,
  planmarks,name=plane]
\psset{plan=plane}
\psProjection[object=cercle,args=0 1 1,range=0 360,
  linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]
\axesIIID(0,0,0)(3,3,3)
\psSolid[
  object=calottesphere,r=2,ngrid=16 18,opacity=0.4,
  linewidth=0.01pt,fillcolor=blue!60,theta=90,phi=0]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-5,-2)(6,6)
\psset{viewpoint=30 80 25 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\psSolid[object=plan,
    definition=normalpoint,args={0 0 0 [0 0 1]},
    base=-2.5 2.5 -2.5 2.5,
    planmarks,name=plane]
    \psset{plan=plane}
\psProjection[object=cercle,args=0 1 1,range=0 360,
    linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]
\axesIIID(0,0,0)(3,3,3)
\psSolid[object=calottesphere,r=2,ngrid=64 72,action=none,
    linewidth=0.01pt,fillcolor=blue!60,theta=90,phi=0,name=sp]
\psSolid[object=cylindrecreux,h=2.5,r=1,fillcolor=white,action=none,
    ngrid=30 72,incolor=green!50,name=py](0,1,0)
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=sp py,opacity=0.8,grid,action=draw**]
\defFunction[algebraic]{g}(t){sin(t)}{cos(t)+1}{2*sin(1/2*t)}
\psset{object=courbe,fillcolor=red,linecolor=red,
    linewidth=0.1,function=g,r=0,action=draw**}
\psSolid[range=0 1.9]\psSolid[range=2.6 3.9]\psSolid[range=5 TwoPi]
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and animated

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{%    
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-6,-3)(6,6)
\psset{viewpoint=30 \iA\space 20 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\psSolid[object=plan,
    definition=normalpoint,args={0 0 0 [0 0 1]},
    base=-2.5 2.5 -2.5 2.5,
    planmarks,name=plane]
    \psset{plan=plane}
\psProjection[object=cercle,args=0 1 1,range=0 360,
    linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed,linewidth=1pt]
\psSolid[object=line,args=1 1 0 1 1 1.41,linecolor=red]
\psSolid[object=line,args=-1 1 0 -1 1 1.41,linecolor=red]
\psSolid[object=line,args=0 0 0 0 0 2,linecolor=red]
\axesIIID(0,0,0)(3,3,3)
\psSolid[
    object=calottesphere,r=2,ngrid=16 18,opacity=0.4,
    linewidth=0.01pt,fillcolor=black!40,theta=90,phi=0,grid]
\defFunction[algebraic]{g}(t){sin(t)}{cos(t)+1}{2*sin(1/2*t)}
\psSolid[object=courbe,range=0 TwoPi,fillcolor=red,linecolor=red,
    linewidth=0.1,function=g,r=0]
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't we plot of function directly x^2+y^2+z^2=4? :-)

Comment: Where is the sense of plotting a sphere with a function? It is already internally defined.

Comment: Where are the previous questions? :-)). What do you think if we print it on the A4 paper? Truly, marmot's answer is best selection to print!

Comment: no, TikZ cannot really handle 3d sufaces. And if you want to print in grayscales then use gray as color. Where is the problem??

Comment: Can you illustrate it if it is printed on the A4 paper?(necessary). I do not your picture can be printed on the A4 paper clearly. P/S: I try to find on PSTricks site but there are no any examples about several things at least for me.

Comment: see edited answer

Answer (score 5):

Hemisphere as a parameterized surface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-2)(6,6)
\psset{viewpoint=30 40 40 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\axesIIID(0,0,0)(3,3,3)
\defFunction[algebraic]{hemisphere}(u,v)
{2*cos(u)*sin(v)}{2*sin(u)*sin(v)}{2*cos(v)}
\psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,
base=0 2 pi mul 0 pi 2 div,
fillcolor=red,
opacity=0.7,
function=hemisphere,
linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
ngrid=36 36]%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]